# Optimization of a regex for a Java identifier. Separating the number in the ending and the other part

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I need to read a string as valid Java identifier and to get separately the number in the ending (if there is any) and the start part.

```
a1 -> a,1
a  -> a,
a123b -> a123b,
ab123 -> ab, 123
a123b456 -> a123b, 456
a123b456c789 -> a123b456c, 789
_a123b456c789 -> _a123b456c, 789
```

I had written a pair of regex that I have tested on http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html, and they look to work OK

```
([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z_]|[a-zA-Z_])(\d+)$
([a-zA-Z_](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z_])?)(\d+)$
```

How can I shorten them? Or can you advice another regex?

I can't change [a-zA-Z_] for \w, for the last takes digits, too.

*(We are talking on regex strings BEFORE replacement \ for \\ in Java/Groovy)*

Comment: Note that in Java/Groovy regex, `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` by default. Only if you pass `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` the `\w` pattern will match all Unicode letters and digits.

Comment: The string must be a variable name. So, I am not searching for all Unicode letters and digits. It is OK here.

Comment: Thinking about your first commentary I came to conclusion, that we can influence, how the shortening patterns such as \\w work?

Comment: Shorthand character classes Unicode behavior can be changed.

Comment: Also, your logic is correct. But if you meant a valid Java identifier, your regex should also be able to match `$` that can appear in Java identifiers.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! We don't use $ for now, but it can be used later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [*Incremental Java*](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Intro/var-ident.html) says:

> - Each identifier must have at least one character.
> - The first character must be picked from: alpha, underscore, or dollar sign. The first character can not be a digit.
> - The rest of the characters (besides the first) can be from: alpha, digit, underscore, or dollar sign. In other words, it can be any valid identifier character.
>     Put simply, an identifier is one or more characters selected from alpha, digit, underscore, or dollar sign. The only restriction is the first character can't be a digit.

And the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) also add:

> The convention, however, is to always begin your variable names with a letter, not "$" or "_". Additionally, the dollar sign character, by convention, is never used at all.

You may use this one that can be used to match *any* valid variable and put the starting chunk of chars into one group and all the trailing digits into another group:

```
^(?!\d)([$\w]+?)(\d*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rAJLc0/1)

Or this one that will only match the identifiers that follow the convention:

```
^(?![\d_])(\w+?)(\d*)$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rAJLc0/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\d)` - the first char cannot be a digit (`(?![\d_])` will fail the match if the first char is digit or `_`)
- `([$\w]+?)` - Group 1: one or more word or `$` chars (the `(\w+?)` will just match letters/digit/`_` chars), as few as possible (as the `+?` is a *lazy* quantifier) up to the first occurrence of...
- `(\d*)$` - Group 2: zero or more digits at the end of string (`$`).

[Groovy demo](http://ideone.com/3tSqdO):

```
// Non-convention Java identifier
def res = 'a123b$456_c789' =~ /^(?!\d)([$\w]+?)(\d*)$/
print("${res[0][1]} : ${res[0][2]}") // => a123b$456_c : 789

// Convention Java identifier
def res2 = 'a123b456_c' =~ /^(?!\d)([$\w]+?)(\d*)$/
print("${res2[0][1]} : ${res2[0][2]}")  // => a123b456_c :
```

Comment: Thank you. I see... yes, I can change [a-zA-Z0-9_] to \\w and I should add ^ at start for checking the start of the string, too. But what is the use of the last '?' ? Change of (\\d+) into (\\d*) will do the same work, won't it?

Comment: And isn't possible to use some different logic? You answer is definitely very useful for me, checking the start of the string, but I am a bit disapointed - logically it is the same as I had found. And I am really a novice in regexes. How could it be that such monster as you sees practically the same solution?

Comment: @Gangnus Not sure what you mean by a "monster". You provided no requirements in the question, there is nothing I can come up myself rather than help you fix *your* code (by deducing the requirements from the patterns you tried).

Comment: I mean your experience in the subject is many times greater than mine. No offence was meant, on the contrary... As for requirements, they are written before my regexes, at the start of the question.

Comment: @Gangnus: Those are not requirements, just some testing cases. You should write explicitly - *valid Java identifiers*.

Comment: Yes, that would be better, definitely. Edited

Comment: I updated to match what you need. Well, it may be written in another way. I added a lookahead based variant.

Comment: Thank you so much for your work - the regex definitely is much better now!

Comment: Oh, sorry, but you have to do one more edit: according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html Java variable cannot START by $ or _. By convention...

Comment: @Gangnus: See [Incremental Java, *Syntax of an Identifier*](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Intro/var-ident.html): *The first character must be picked from: alpha, underscore, or dollar sign. The first character can not be a digit.*

Comment: Ok, I see, so you might need 2 regex variations, one for convention way, and the other for any valid identifiers.

Comment: You are right, of course. I only tried to help to improve your answer for people in future.

Comment: I see, I only kept the 2 shorter variations.

Comment: Sorry, both your new regexs, however nice-looking, won't recognize a123b$456_c789

Comment: @Gangnus: [No, the first one will](https://regex101.com/r/CW6ckh/1) as it matches *any* valid Java identifiers. The `a123b$456_c789` does not follow the convention, so you can't match it with `^(?![\d_])(\w+?)(\d*)$`

Comment: Oh! Really. I have misclicked. Sorry. Now I will study your regexes and will try to understand them :-)

Comment: Feel free to start a chat whenever you need any clarifications.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149971/discussion-between-gangnus-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I tried to make my solution as simple as I could but I didn't think about it long enough so it is incorrect. Just look at the accepted answer

I believe you can shorten it to `^([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_\d]*[^\d])(\d*)$` - match all possible characters with not a number at the end, and a number.

Comment: `^([a-zA-Z_\d]*[^\d])(\d*)$` is not correct because a variable name cannot start with a digit.

Comment: Yes, I just realised that. Edited to get it right.(Hopefully)

Comment: No, `[^\d]` means *any char other than digit*. Any.

Comment: I edited that before your second comment. Now I don't know if it's even shorter than what it was in the question.

Comment: It is not the question of writing something shorter. `[^\d]` matches `#`, `*`, `Ł`, `Щ`...